# Display none on label with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i looked on stackoverflow to correct my error but could not find any answers that helped, so i want my label to get display none when i click on the label and i want display block on an ul element, the ul element get's the display block but the label does not here's my code:

```js
var menuCheck = document.getElementById(checkBox);
var menuDims = document.getElementById(menuUl);
var labelUl = document.getElementById(labelUl);
        
function menuFunction() {
          
  menuDims.style.display="block";
  labelUl.style.display="none";
          
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <checkbox id="checkBox"></checkbox> 
  <label for="checkbox" onclick="menuFunction()" id="labelUl">l</label>
  <ul id="menuUl">
    <li><a href="index.html">Forside</a></li>
    <li><a href="spil.html">Spil</a></li>
    <li><a href="an.html">Anmeldelser</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to fix:

```
var menuCheck = document.getElementById('checkBox');
var menuDims = document.getElementById('menuUl');
var labelUl = document.getElementById('labelUl');
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible issues is, you need

```
document.getElementById("checkBox")
```

i.e. you need to double or single quote the id name.

Answer (score 0):

Since menuCheck and other variables are not defined because the statements are not executed

```
function menuFunction() {
  var menuCheck = document.getElementById(checkBox);
  var menuDims = document.getElementById(menuUl);
  var labelUl = document.getElementById(label);
  menuDims.style.display="block";
  labelUl.style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[getElementById MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

var labelUl = document.getElementById(label);

is where the problem lies

the ID does not match the element

```
<label for="checkbox" onclick="menuFunction()" id="**labelUl**">l</label>
```

the line should look like this

```
var labelUl = document.getElementById("labelUl");
var menuDims = document.getElementById("menuUl");
```

all your other ID's are except the checkbox one are correct but need the ID passed to be pass as a string

```
var menuCheck = document.getElementById(checkBox);
```

not entirely sure what this is doing but it doesn't match any element shown in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById takes a string as a parameter, see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for more info and examples.
And the script tag needs to be run after the elements are added to the document.
So putting the script tag after the `<nav>` should also help.

[working example](http://jsbin.com/jezariqapa/edit?html,output)